# Pandas latitude longitude binning to 100x100 bins

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have huge dataset of latitude and longitudes with other KPIs related to it, what I want to achieve is I want to bin the latitude and longitudes to group of 100x100 area bin and then aggregate other KPIs by grouping them by using the lat long bin. I tried this method before

```
step = 0.001
to_bin = lambda x: np.floor(x / step) * step
data["latbin"] = data['client_latitude'].map(to_bin)
data["lonbin"] = data['client_longitude'].map(to_bin)
```

but it didn't work as expected
So how do I achieve the 100x100 binning of lat longs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_bin` is return a float, you can format it to a string and concat the lat and long togather:

```
to_bin = lambda x: '%0.3f' % (np.floor(x / step) * step)
data["bin"] = data['client_latitude'].map(to_bin) + 'x' + \
              data['client_longitude'].map(to_bin)
```